# Вывод массива в два столбца

Tags: php, html

Есть массив в такой структуре

```
[Алтайский край] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Барнаул
                    [1] => Алтайский край
                )

        )

    [Белгородская область] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Белгород
                    [1] => Белгородская область
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Старый Оскол
                    [1] => Белгородская область
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Щебекино
                    [1] => Белгородская область
                )

        )
```

Необходимо вывести его в таком виде, что бы сначала показывались название региона, а потом список городов принадлежащих этому региону. И самое главное, чтобы список регионов располагался в две колонки т.е в левой колонке выводились к примеру регионы от А до Л, а потом от Л до Я

```
ksort($region_group);
          print_r($region_group);
            $cnt=0;
            $half=round(count($region_group)/2);
            echo "<div class='list_region'>";
            foreach($region_group as $key => $city){
                if($cnt<=$half){
                    echo "<div class='left'>";
                    echo "<div class='region_choose'>".$key."</div>";
                        foreach($city as $val){  
                            echo "<div class='city'>".$val[0]."</div>";
                        } 
                     echo "</div>";
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='right'>";
                    echo "<div class='region_choose'>".$key."</div>";
                        foreach($city as $val){  
                            echo "<div class='city'>".$val[0]."</div>";
                        } 
                    echo "</div>";
                }
                $cnt++; 
            }
            echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Рекомендую расположить колонки средствами CSS

Comment: напишите, пожалста, как это может выглядеть

Comment: Пользуйтесь поиском по сайту :) ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327481/Как-сделать-список-в-два-столбца?

Comment: честно скажу ваш вариант с css мне даже очень подошёл, лучше добавьте его т.к кому-то может это понадобится. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многие браузеры поддерживают размещение в нескольких [колонках](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns). Просто сформируйте единый список и добавьте стили.

```css
.list_region {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
     -moz-columns: 2;
          columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list_region">
  <li class="city">Астрахань
  </li>
  <li class="city">Воронеж
  </li>
  <li class="city">Москва
  </li>
  <li class="city">Омск
  </li>
  <li class="city">Саратов
  </li>
</ul>
```

PS. Для списков стоит использовать теги списков.